# Javascript RegEx - Start and End of String Anomalies

Tags: javascript, regex

So im trying some really basic RegEx out for the first time and I've been told that theres a few ways of stating the start and end of the string.

One way would be '`\A`' & '`\Z`' and the other would be '`^`' & '`$`'.

For some reason when running this in JS, the later is the only option that actually works.

Does anyone know why that might be please?

```
var str = "123456",
    pattern1 = new RegExp("^\\d{6}$"),
    pattern2 = new RegExp("\A\\d{6}\Z");

if(pattern1.test(str)){
    alert('pattern 1 match!'); 
}else{
    alert('pattern 1 no match!'); 
}

if(pattern2.test(str)){
    alert('pattern 2 match!'); 
}else{
    alert('pattern 2 no match!'); 
}
```

Comment: Because js regex is designed like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think whoever told you that `\A` and `\Z` are supposed to work was misinformed. Based on the [JavaScript Regular Expressions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters), only `^` and `$` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Have a little play with a regex visualizer, like [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/). It shows that [your expression matches](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PG8wIKOqCDOCHW2b) when *PCRE* or *Python* is selected as the regex flavor (in the drop-down), but doesn't match when using the *Javascript* flavor.

In short, Javascript simply [doesn't support `\A` and `\Z`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters).